# Luis List Entities and Synonyms

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I'm attempting to use list entities for my chat bot when dealing with environments and am having trouble finding information on using synonyms.

Lets say I have a dev, test, and prod environment.  I want these environments limited to the normalized list items but I also want production to be a synonym for 'prod'.  I would expect when a user asks 'Perform action x on production' that the 'environment' entity would be 'prod' because production is a synonym for prod.  This is not the case though and the entity returns as 'production' instead.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the purpose of the synonyms?

Link to screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoPAv.png

Answer (score 1):

You are proceeding almost correct. There is slight confusion while using "Test panel" inside LUIS.ai UI.

You have two options to get what you want.

1) While inspecting result in "Test panel" click "Compare with published" and then click at "Show JSON view" and you'll something like:

[image]

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-interactive-test for more details.

2) use http GET towards REST API in your browser as an alternative: 
https://yourLocaltion.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/youAppId?subscription-key=yourSubscirptionId&q=lock%20development

The results in your case should be:

```
{
  "query": "lock development",
  "topScoringIntent": { ...
  },
  "entities": [
    {
      "entity": "development",
      "type": "Environment",
      "startIndex": 5,
      "endIndex": 15,
      "resolution": {
        "values": [
          "Dev"
        ]
...
```

See section "Manage" > "Keys and Endpoints" in your LUIS app administration to get details about correct url for using REST API.